# Hide validation Message when page is not posted yet in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use AddModelError in MVC to show error messages, but my problem is when I go to the page before entering value I also see the error message. I want to see the message after pushing the submit and when the email is empty. 
This is my controller methods:

```
    [Route("forgotPassword")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordRequest forgotPasswordRequest)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                   .....
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", Constants.MessageStrings.NoUser);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", Constants.MessageStrings.RequiredFields);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          ...
        return PartialView(message);
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
<div>
<p>Please enter the Email Address associated with your account and we will email you a link to reset your password.</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("forgotPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <label>
        Email Address
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="jdoe@example.com">
    </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
}
```

Comment: are you saying that you see the validation errors when the page loads (in the initial GET request to the page) ?

Comment: @Shyju  Yes, I see the error message when I directed to page before I click on submit as it goes to else statement.

Comment: what else statement ? You see the error message when you submit the form or when you load the GET action method response for the first time ?

Comment: I see the message when page load for first time.

Comment: That sounds strange! Can you share the GET action method code  ?

Comment: I don't have get, I use only this method for both. so when it is get  if (ModelState.IsValid) is false.

Comment: You dont add `ModelState` errors in a GET method. You need 2 methods, a GET to initially display the data, and a POST (and you GET method should not have a parameter for the model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to break apart your controller action into to distinct methods. The first would only return a new `ForgotPasswordRequest`, while the second would check the `ModelState` and perform the actual password request work.

First (GET)

```
[Route("forgotPassword")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword()
{
   // no validation, just returns a new ForgotPasswordRequest for the the view
}
```

Second (POST)

```
[Route("forgotPassword")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordRequest forgotPasswordRequest)
{
    // checks the ModelState and performs the any other actions
}
```